# HTML list to R dataframe

Tags: html, r, list, dataframe, rvest

I have the following example html code below. I would like to have a dataframe as follows. Thank you very much for any ideas

```
<a name="efficiant"></a><h3>Ingredient</h3>
<div id="product_detail"><ul>
<li>X1<ul>
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>X2<ul>
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>X3<ul>
<li>c</li>
<li>b</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>


column A    column B
   X1          a
   X1          b
   X1          c
   X2          a
   X2          b
   X3          c
   X3          b
```

Comment: your html is complicated.is it in correct format..like i can see `<li>X1<ul>` like tags,this html is wrong i guess.

Comment: @RajithThennakoon I don't think there is anything wrong with the html. It's a nested `ul` structure within a `li` structure. You should be able to extract relevant bits using `rvest` and suitable CSS selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure this can be optimised but here is an `rvest` option using some CSS selectors to extract the nested `li` elements from within the `ul`s.

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

val <- read_html(ss) %>%
    html_nodes(css = "li > ul") %>%
    map(~html_nodes(.x, css = "li") %>% html_text())

nms <- read_html(ss) %>%
    html_nodes(css = "li") %>%
    html_text() %>%
    str_extract("X\\d") %>%
    na.omit()

stack(setNames(val, nms))
#  values ind
#1      a  X1
#2      b  X1
#3      c  X1
#4      a  X2
#5      b  X2
#6      c  X3
#7      b  X3
```

---

### Sample data

```
ss <- '<a name="efficiant"></a><h3>Ingredient</h3>
<div id="product_detail"><ul>
<li>X1<ul>
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>X2<ul>
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>X3<ul>
<li>c</li>
<li>b</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
'
```

Answer (score 1):

If your HTML is in correct format,you can do it like this

```
library(rvest)
html = '<a name="efficiant"></a><h3>Ingredient</h3>
<div id="product_detail">
<ul>
<li>X1</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>X2</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>X3</li>
<li>c</li>
<li>b</li>
</ul>
</div>
'
df <- data.frame()
page<-read_html(html) 
page %>% html_nodes("ul") -> uls
for (ul in uls) {
  ul %>% html_text("li") -> text
  text = gsub('\\n', ' ', text)
  vec <- unlist(strsplit(text, "\\s+"))
  A <- rep(vec[1],length(vec)-1)
  B <- vec[2:length(vec)]
  tmpdf <- data.frame(A,B)
  df <- rbind(df,tmpdf)
}
```

output

```
   A B
1 X1 a
2 X1 b
3 X1 c
4 X2 a
5 X2 b
6 X3 c
7 X3 b
```